# How to include a html email with images in Servlet & send

Tags: java, html, jsp, email, servlets

I have a servlet which handles user registration. This servlet also sends an activation email to the user. I have implemented Mail sending in another class but here's the function which handles sending the mail to the user:

```
if(localEjb.createUser(usr) != null)
        {
            boolean status = true;

            EmailSetting emailSetting = localEjb.fetchSetting();

            if(emailSetting != null)
            {
                Mail mail = new Mail();

                String message = "Dear " + lastName + " , "  +
                        "Your account has been created on Eventry. " +
                        "Please click this link '" + emailSetting.getBaseURL() + "activate?" + securityCode + "' to complete the activation process";

                status = mail.send(emailSetting, emailSetting.getRecipient(), email, Message.EVENTRY_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_INSTRUCTIONS, message, null, null);
            }

            /*this user has been successfully created on the portal*/
            this.respond(response, status, status ? Message.activation_mail_sent : Message.activation_mail_failed,null);
        }
        else
        {
            // a technical error occureed, we couldn't create the user (Should never happen)
            this.respond(response, true, Message.registration_failed + Message.technical_fault, null);
        }
```

Now, as you can see, I have written the message to be sent in a very simple way and it works. But what I really need now is to have a custom email complete with CSS and HTML. I already have this, but I can't figure out how I will plug it into the servlet. Or if I can use JSP, how should I go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Google for `java send html email with images`, there is really **a lot** of examples and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the challenge is not getting the HTML into the message, it is the CSS that is the problem. Thanks. P.s I think before anybody down-votes my question they should at least advice on what I can do.

Comment: Well, most of the results of such search discuss not only how to send HTML e-mail, but also how to embed other objects - images, CSS, etc. - into such HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can `forward` to a JSP and provide a `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to substitute the JSP's `ServletResponse.getWriter` with a StringWriter.

However an email has specific properties, that need testing, like what the HTML exactly looks like. The email must be of text/html content type, maybe best have a fallback to text/plain. The images must come with the mail. CSS is still a tender subject.

So I would split the task in

- make a simple HTML with an image and send that HTML
- make a JSP that fills in placeholders
- make complexer HTML, realizing the desired layout
- test in several email clients (web, outlook, apps)